# What are the plataforms/devices Ubuntu touch will run from?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

Having been a first day contributor to Edge (shame it didn't get there) I appreciate phones & tablets running Ubuntu is the aim, for next year.

In the meantime, can you please clarify what platform / devices Ubuntu mobile will run on - On top of or side by side with android, or what?

Sorry if this is available elsewhere, but if it is I've missed it, I couldn't find the answer.

I'm interested in writing apps, but would like to try them on real devices and may want to roll out a live app this autumn.
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Touch is officialy supported on Nexus S, Nexus 4, Nexus 7 and Nexus 10.
Thanks to the community is also available for an high number of others devices, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

As long as I know there are no devices where you can do dual-boot, but I can be wrong.

Ubuntu Touch does not run on Android (Ubuntu for Android does it) but is a indipendent system, like on computers!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is currently aiming for a converged platform, this take 3 paths currently and will gradually merge into one.

Ubuntu desktop: i386 and amd64 on unity7, in 14.10 this will become unity8 that is currently being deployed on the Phone/Tablet.

Ubuntu for Android: This is your standard android phone but when docked has an ubuntu desktop.

Unity 8/Ubuntu touch:  Unity 8 is what is being rolled out on our current phone images and this will be the fully converged operating system that will power phones, tablets, desktops and tv's.

For development if you go to http://developer.ubuntu.com that will give you most info.  If you are on Saucy already the sdk for QML/QT is available, if you are anything older than that there is a ppa to get at it.

Device wise anything that currently has android on it is a potential device that can run Ubuntu touch.  You can see the porting guide https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting here.

I hope that answers everything.